# Finding all possible sum combinations of given column in R

Tags: r

R data frame 1 :

| Index | Powervalue |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 16 |
| 5 | 32 |

R dataframe 2 :

| CombinedValue |
| --- |
| 20 |
| 50 |

Expected Final Result :

| CombinedValue | possiblecodes |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 4, 16 |
| 50 | 2, 16, 32 |

Can we get the output as in the image. If yes please help.

[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz2lr.jpg)

Comment: What is the logic? How did you obtain the final table?

Comment: Am looking for the R code to get the expected table by using first 2 dataframes since am new to this R

Comment: And how did you obtain the expected table from the first 2?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack overflow.  Can you tell us how to decide which elements should end up in the "possiblecodes" column?  It is just binary representation of the CombinedCode value?

Comment: Possible sum of power values with comma seperated for the values 20 and 50

Comment: Can you help to get the output as attached image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
df <- data.frame(sum = c(50, 20, 6))
values_list <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  sum <- df$sum[i]
  values <- c()
  while (sum > 0) {
    value <- 2^floor(log2(sum))
    values <- c(values, value)
    sum <- sum - value
  }
  values_list[[i]] <- values
}
df$values <- values_list
```

df is now:

```
    sum    values
1   50    32, 16, 2
2   20    16, 4
3   6     4, 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and prompt response.

Comment: I got the same result however when I do View(df) am getting c(16, 4) instead of 16, 4

Comment: Can you help to get the output as attached image